# excel formula to copy paste and transpose the value of the duplicate

Tags: excel

Hi please need help i need some formula or macro to copy and paste the duplicate and transpose[image]

Comment: It is unclear from your narrative and example whether you want to flatten the original data or expand the original data. For that matter, which **is** the original and which is the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you know the maximum number of duplicates, a formula based solution is not recommended. It would also not be recommended for a relatively large number of values or dynamic data that changes often (negating the predetermined maximum  number of duplicates).

VBA solution:

1. If the data is not sorted with column A being the primary key, sort it.
2. Loop through the values in column A from the bottom to the top.
3. Every time a value in column A changes from the last one recorded, record the new value and use `application.match` to find the row number of the first occurrence of that value.
4. Use `offset`, `resize` and `transpose` to copy and flip the values from the first occurrence to the last occurrence (into column C and right of the first occurrence).
5. Continue with the loop until you reach row 2.